# How can I optimize my array_join (simulates a LEFT JOIN) function?

Tags: php

I wrote the following code to take arrays in PHP and "join" them together the way that a LEFT JOIN would in MySQL. For my sake I wrote the function using foreach and passed the arrays in and returned a new array... I feel like it's pretty readable, but I also know that it's inefficient.

Ideally, I'd like this function to handle upwards of 10,000 rows per array, and I suspect that means: 1) passing $original by reference (to save memory), and 2) using one of PHP iterative array function rather than a foreach (to save processing time).

Usually I don't post these sort of "quiz" like questions, but I feel like the answer to this will benefit the community. (Like this guy: [Join 2 multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833522/join-2-multidimensional-array))

May the 1) fastest, and 2) lowest memory consuming answer win! :P

```
<?php

// Join Arrays on Keys (**updated with knittl's suggestion**)
function array_join($original, $merge, $on) {
    if (!is_array($on)) $on = array($on);
    foreach ($merge as $remove => $right) {
        foreach ($original as $index => $left) {
            foreach ($on as $from_key => $to_key) {
                if (!isset($original[$index][$from_key])
                    || !isset($right[$to_key])
                    || $original[$index][$from_key] != $right[$to_key])
                    continue 2;
            }
            $original[$index] = array_merge($left, $right);
            unset($merge[$remove]);
        }
    }
    return array_merge($original, $merge);
}

// Test Arrays
$data1 = array(
    array(
        'productId' => '822335',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 06:00:00',
        'qtySold' => '200',
        'qtyCanceled' => '10',
    ),
    array(
        'productId' => '822335',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 07:00:00',
        'qtySold' => '100',
        'qtyCanceled' => '20',
    ),
    array(
        'productId' => '822336',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 06:00:00',
        'qtySold' => '0',
        'qtyCanceled' => '30',
    ),
    array(
        'productId' => '822336',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 07:00:00',
        'qtySold' => '50',
        'qtyCanceled' => '40',
    ),
);

$data2 = array(
    array(
        'entity_id' => '822335',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 06:00:00',
        'productInventory' => '300',
    ),
    array(
        'entity_id' => '822335',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 07:00:00',
        'productInventory' => '200',
    ),
    array(
        'entity_id' => '822336',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 06:00:00',
        'productInventory' => '100',
    ),
    array(
        'entity_id' => '822336',
        'dateHour' => '2011-11-17 07:00:00',
        'productInventory' => '50',
    ),
);

// Usage
$result = array_join($data1, $data2, array(
    'productId' => 'entity_id',
    'dateHour' => 'dateHour'
));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Add a `break` to your innermost foreach+if … this should speed up execution tremendously.

Comment: Here are the three "basic" kinds of join techniques: `LOOP`, `HASH`, `MERGE`. Which one is the above? How would the others work? What is the Big-O of each?

Comment: @knittl: Unfortunately breaking out of any of the foreach's would prevent the multi-key matching to work.

Comment: @CalebGray: `foreach ($on as $from_key => $to_key) {                if (!isset...) $match = false; }` You never change `$match` back to TRUE. So changing it to `{ $match = FALSE; break; }` will definitely help. a lot. Using the `continue;` statement to skip one iteration of the outer loop would even help to spare that state variable (`$match`).

Comment: @knittl: Oh, you're totally right! Hah! I spoke before rereading my implementation. I'll update my question. ^_^

Comment: I think you got your conditional wrong. It now merges when the keys are not set.

Comment: I'm really making myself look bad, you're totally right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better?

```
function array_join($original, $merge, $on) {
    if (!is_array($on)) $on = array($on);
    foreach ($merge as $remove => $right) {
        foreach ($original as $index => $left) {
            foreach ($on as $from_key => $to_key) {
                if (!isset($original[$index][$from_key])
                || !isset($right[$to_key])
                || $original[$index][$from_key] != $right[$to_key])
                    continue 2;
            }
            $original[$index] = array_merge($left, $right);
            unset($merge[$remove]);
        }
    }
    return array_merge($original, $merge);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Looks like your optimization is the one that I wanted. ^_^

Comment: @knittl why did you do     return array_merge($original, $merge)    and not just         return $original

Comment: @CalebGray ^^ the same question if you know the answer

Comment: @Nathan: after almost 4 years, I really can't say anymore. It will add all keys still left in the `$merge` array.