# PHP: merge multidimensional, associative arrays (LEFT JOIN simulation - keep duplicates, keep non-existent elements)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got two associative, multidimensional arrays **$arrayOffered** and  **$arraySold**. I would like to merge them under certain conditions:

- if value of key 'item' from *$arrayOffered* exists in *$arraySold*, both elements should be included in array **$result**. If for 1 element from *$arrayOffered* there are 3 elements in *$arraySold*, I should get also 3 elements in **$result**.
- otherwise, element from *$arrayOffered* should be added into **$result**.

One element from *$arrayOffered* can have >1 equivalents in *$arraySold*. They should be joined in the way shown below.

**Input data**:

```
$arrayOffered = array(
          0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'Category' => 'ABC'), 
          1 => array('item' => 'product_2', 'Category' => 'DEF')
          );  

$arraySold = array(
          0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'ItemsSold' => '2', 'ItemsReturned' => 1), //arrays in this array can contain up to 30 elements
          1 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'ItemsSold' => '1')
          );
```

**Desired result:**

```
$desiredResult = array( 
        0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'Category' => 'ABC', 'ItemsSold' => '2', 'ItemsReturned' => 1),
        1 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'Category' => 'ABC', 'ItemsSold' => '1'),
        2 => array('item' => 'product_2', 'Category' => 'DEF')
        );
```

I got stuck on something like:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arrayOffered as $keyOffered => $offeredSubArr)
{
    $item = $offeredSubArr['item'];
    foreach($arraySold as $keySold => $soldSubArr)
    {
        if(isset($soldSubArr['item']) && $soldSubArr['item'] == $item) 
        {   
            $i = 0;
            $test = array_merge($offeredSubArr, $soldSubArr);
            $result[$i][] = $test;
            $i++;
        }
        else 
        {
          $result[$i][] = $offeredSubArr;
          $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:
- output array isn't formatted the way I wanted
- I know I'm not going in the right direction. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is actually a `LEFT JOIN` like in sql. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764309) can help

Comment: Yes, it's similar to LEFT JOIN but not the same. (For instance product_2 should be shown once, not twice).

Comment: Why should product_2 appear twice in a left join? There is no product_2 in `$arraySold`, so it would only appear once in the result, just as desired.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Nevertheless, from what I see, my example is a little bit different from yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option, since you have this $arrayOffered as a kind of master file I suggest to build a hash with this array and use later on the foreach look for sold array.

```
$arrayOffered = array(
          0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'Category' => 'ABC'), 
          1 => array('item' => 'product_2', 'Category' => 'DEF')
          );  

$arraySold = array(
          0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'ItemsSold' => '2', 'ItemsReturned' => 1), //arrays in this array can contain up to 30 elements
          1 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'ItemsSold' => '1')
          );

//Build a hash to get the extra properties
$hashArray = array();
foreach ($arrayOffered as $offered) {
    $hashArray[$offered['item']]=$offered;
}

$resultArray = array();
foreach ($arraySold as $sold) {
    $hashItem = $hashArray[$sold['item']];  
    // you dont want this sold flag on your final result
    unset($hashItem['sold']);
    $resultArray[]=array_merge($hashItem,$sold);
    $hashArray[$sold['item']]['sold']= true;
}
//Add all the missing hash items
foreach($hashArray as $hashItem){
    if(!isset($hashItem['sold'])){
        $resultArray[]=$hashItem; 
    }
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

Test sample
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f48ceb3deb328088209fbaef4f01d8d4430478db

Comment: Ok, but product_2 is not included in $result.

Comment: You are right, edited adding control to the hash to know if has been added

Comment: I think I should accept your answer as a shorter one.  Thank you dminones and @Akis too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
            foreach ($arrayOffered as $keyOffered => $offeredSubArr)
            {
                $item = $offeredSubArr['item'];
                foreach($arraySold as $keySold => $soldSubArr)
                { $i = 0;
                    if(isset($soldSubArr['item']) && $soldSubArr['item'] == $item) 
                    {   

                        $test = array_merge($offeredSubArr, $soldSubArr);                       
                        $result[$i][] = $test;

                    }
                    else 
                    {

                        $result[$i][] = $offeredSubArr;                   

                    }


                    $i++;
                }
            }
            $result = $result[0];
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); die();
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but product_2 (this one which doesn't exist in $arraySold) must be pushed only once in $result.

Answer (score 1):

Well i will try to follow your logic although there is simpler solutions. 
First of all we will need to search in a multidimentional array thats why we will need the followed function from [this so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764309/how-can-i-optimize-my-array-join-simulates-a-left-join-function)

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Next after small changes:

- $i you don't need to make it zero on every loop just once so place it outside
- unnecessary [] ($result[$i][]) you don't need the empty brackets no reason to create an extra table in the $i row since what you add there, the $test is already table itself
- Adding the last loop coz when sth is not in the second table it will be added in your new table in every loop and as far as i get you don't want that kind of duplicates

We have the following code:

```
 $arrayOffered = array(
      0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'Category' => 'ABC'), 
      1 => array('item' => 'product_2', 'Category' => 'DEF')
      );  

 $arraySold = array(
      0 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'ItemsSold' => '2', 'ItemsReturned' => 1), //arrays in this array can contain up to 30 elements
      1 => array('item' => 'product_1', 'ItemsSold' => '1')
      );
 $i = 0;
 $result = array();
 foreach ($arrayOffered as $keyOffered => $offeredSubArr)
 {
     $item = $offeredSubArr['item'];
     foreach($arraySold as $keySold => $soldSubArr)
     {
          if(isset($soldSubArr['item']) && $soldSubArr['item'] == $item) 
          {   
               $test = array_merge($offeredSubArr, $soldSubArr);
               $result[$i] = $test;
               $i++;
          }
     }
}
foreach ($arrayOffered as $value)
{
     if (!in_array_r($value['item'], $result))
     {
          $result[$i] = $value;
          $i++;
     }
 }
 print_r($result);
```

Which as far as i tested gives the wanted result.

Comment: I've accepted another solution because it seems more efficient to me, but thank you anyway for your time and helpful explanations!